# firebase snapshot listener create many LIST requests

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, firebase-tools

I have a react component in which I need to read some data from firestore. I am using real time time updates via a onSnapshot function inside of a useEffect call with a return , like so:

```
  const {id} = useParams()
  const [enrolled, setEnrolled] = useState(null) 

  //listener for new enrolled students
  useEffect(() => {
    const enrolledRef = collection(db, `modules/${id}/enrolled/`)
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(enrolledRef, (snapshot) => {
      let list = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        list.push({id:doc.id, ...doc.data()})
      })
      setEnrolled(list)
    }, (error)=> {
      console.log(error)
    });
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [])
```

But, testing this with the firebase emulator, I see a lot of LIST requests sent to the DB, like so:

[image: emulator screenshot showing several LIST requests]

Where am I going wrong with my onSnapshot listener set up? Is this behaviour normal?